# Highchart - Changing label text of the yaxis programatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have searched over the net and the highchart documentation, for the option required to change the label of the yaxis for a graph (let's say spline).

I have gotten close to

```
chart.yAxis[0].options.label
```

Which seems to be valid, but could not figure out how to use it.

Also, **if you have multiple yaxis, how do we get a yaxis object by its id**, so that I can manipulate its particular label.

Note: Not title text, I am looking for label.

Right now statically setting it like this -

`chart.addAxis({
.
.
.
title: {
  text: "my label",
  align: "high",
  y: -20,
  rotation: 0,
},
.
.
});`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. A specific label along the yaxis? What criteria? There are several way to modify these within the API.

Comment: Well, I am able to set them when I build the yaxis, like specified in the edit. Just need to find out how to edit it once the graph is plotted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`axis.update()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update). This will let you modify just about anything about an axis. To get which axis to update you can specify by the index (the order in which you added he axis starting at 0).